# Building complex functions with lens library

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I'm trying to implement a function that has a `lens` argument and will `mconcat` a `Maybe` monoid with two applicative effects of type `(->) r`. I am probably missing some basics, so any help in decomposing this problem is appreciated.

I want to write 'user' code that avoids passing the same arguments, something like this:

```
z pom root [(textFrom "groupId"), (textFrom "artifactId"), (textFrom "version")]

textFrom :: Text -> Document -> Lens' Document Element -> Maybe Text
textFrom name pom ln = listToMaybe $ pom ^.. ln ./ ell name . text
```

Here is what I tried. Concept without lens:

```
Prelude Data.Monoid Control.Applicative> let f a b = Just $ show (a+1) ++ b
Prelude Data.Monoid Control.Applicative> let z a b xs = mconcat $ ($ b) <$> ($ a) <$> xs
Prelude Data.Monoid Control.Applicative> z 3 "x" [f,f]
Just "4x4x"
```

With lens:

```
z :: (forall f. Functor f, Monoid b)  => Document -> ((Element -> f Element) -> Document -> f Document) -> [Document -> ((Element -> f Element) -> Document -> f Document) -> b] -> b
z pom ln xs = mconcat $ ($ ln) <$> ($ pom) <$> xs
```

But it fails to compile:

```
    Couldn't match expected type ‘[a0
                               -> Document
                               -> [Document
                                   -> ((Element -> f Element) -> Document -> f Document) -> b]
                               -> b]’
            with actual type ‘(Element -> f Element) -> Document -> f Document’
Relevant bindings include
  xs :: (Element -> f Element) -> Document -> f Document
    (bound at Main.hs:27:10)
  z :: (forall (f1 :: * -> *). Functor f1)
       -> Monoid b =>
          Document
          -> ((Element -> f Element) -> Document -> f Document)
          -> [Document
              -> ((Element -> f Element) -> Document -> f Document) -> b]
          -> b
    (bound at Main.hs:27:1)
Probable cause: ‘xs’ is applied to too few arguments
In the second argument of ‘(<$>)’, namely ‘xs’
In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘($ ln) <$> ($ pom) <$> xs’
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes, storing lenses in containers can cause issues but we can circumvent these by using `ALens'`. Conceptually, `ALens' Element Document` is more or less the same as `Functor f => ((Element -> f Element) -> Document -> f Document)`, but you can put it into a container with fewer problems. An important thing to note is that each lens is universally qualified over all `Functor`s, so the original signature should actually look more like this (although this won't quite work):

```
z :: (Monoid b)
  => Document
  -> (forall f. Functor f => (Element -> f Element) -> Document -> f Document)
  -> [Document -> (forall f. Functor f => (Element -> f Element) -> Document -> f Document) -> b]
  -> b
```

If we give `z` a type using `ALens'`, we end up with this (assuming you are using the `lens` library. If not, see the note at the bottom):

```
 z :: (Monoid b)
   => Document
   -> ALens' Element Document
   -> [Document -> ALens' Element Document -> b]
```

With this new signature, the original definition that you gave will work.

We can simplify this definition using a different `Monoid` instance. The `Monoid b => (a -> b)` `Monoid` instance combines functions that have the a `Monoid` result type. Here is an example:

```
lengthSum :: [a] -> Sum Int
lengthSum xs = Sum (length xs)

λ> (lengthSum <> lengthSum) "abc"
Sum {getSum = 6}
```

The `(<>)` method `mappend`s the results of applying each function to the given argument (so it ends up being essentially the same as `length "abc" + length "abc"`). Likewise, `mconcat` will combine the results of a list of functions. This also extends to functions of more than one argument, as long as each function is the same type and the result type is an instance of `Monoid`.

With this instance in hand, we can define:

```
z pom ln xs = mconcat xs pom ln
```

This definition works with both the lens and non-lens version of the type.

If you are not using the `lens` library, you should be able to define something like `ALens'` as

```
newtype ALens s t a b = ALens
  { getLens :: forall f. Functor f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t
  }
type ALens' s a = ALens s s a a
```

Comment: ALens is actually defined differently, in a way that you can use any lens as an ALens too (fixing `f` to be a functor that allows lens to recover the "real" lens). You can use `cloneLens` to recover the "real" lens.

Comment: @bennofs I saw that, but will defining `ALens` this way work for these purposes or will I run into issues? Is it mostly to avoid the need for wrapping lenses in a data constructor? I wanted to avoid the extra complexity that the `lens` version of `ALens` (seems) to bring, if possible, so that the underlying issue is easier to understand.